# how should i add sound in android studio which plays on button click

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, android-application-class

this is my code

```
fun onclick(view: View) {
    val numberRandom = (1..6).random()
    textView1.text = "$numberRandom"

    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rolll.wav)
    mediaPlayer?.start() // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: ok, sorry for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't include .wav extension in your resource, it should be

```
R.raw.rolll
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your logcat? Do you have your resource properly placed and called?

Comment: it does not shows any errors but in my android device the music is not getting played

Comment: not in android  device check the logcat in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `R.raw.rolll`
not extension with it like below

```
MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rolll)
```

with regrads

xitij

Comment: check logcat i'm sure there will something about it

Comment: are you sure the file name is rolll or not roll (it can be a typo) ??